# How to get user profiles on Sharepoint 2013 using REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, onedrive-for-business

I created a Web app using Office365 preview APIs to to consume Office 365 Services with full permissions to services(including UserProfile.Read permission)

I am trying to get all user profiles using the REST API.

I tried the below url on postman(chrome app) by passing access token in headers.

https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties

I was asked to enter the admin's credentials.

So how to get user profiles using access token but not by giving credentials.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Since you are building application using [Office 365 APIs Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605892(v=office.15).aspx), [Azure AD Graph API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974476.aspx) could be utilized for getting user details (`Users and Groups` service on the picture below).

[image]

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve users using [Azure AD Graph API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974476.aspx) (excerpt from ASP.NET MVC App):

```
public static class UserManager
{
    const string ServiceResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net/";
    static readonly Uri ServiceEndpointUri = new Uri("https://graph.windows.net/");
    static DiscoveryContext _discoveryContext;

    public static async Task<IEnumerable<IUser>> GetUsers()
    {
        var client = await EnsureClientCreated();
        var userResults = await client.DirectoryObjects.OfType<IUser>().ExecuteAsync();
        var allUsers = new List<IUser>();

        do
        {
            allUsers.AddRange(userResults.CurrentPage);
            userResults = await userResults.GetNextPageAsync();
        } while (userResults != null);

        return allUsers;
    }

    public static async Task<AadGraphClient> EnsureClientCreated()
    {
        if (_discoveryContext == null)
        {
            _discoveryContext = await DiscoveryContext.CreateAsync();
        }

        var dcr = await _discoveryContext.DiscoverResourceAsync(ServiceResourceId);

        return new AadGraphClient(new Uri(ServiceEndpointUri, dcr.TenantId), async () =>
        {
            return (await _discoveryContext.AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenByRefreshTokenAsync(new SessionCache().Read("RefreshToken"), new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential(_discoveryContext.AppIdentity.ClientId, _discoveryContext.AppIdentity.ClientSecret), ServiceResourceId)).AccessToken;
        });
    }
}
```

Key points:

- The Azure Active Directory Graph API (`AadGraphClient Class`) is used for
  getting a user’s detailed properties
- [ClientCredential Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.clientcredential.aspx) is used for authentication in O365 by
  providing `client id` and `secret`.

**Usage**

```
public class O365UserManagementController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        try
        {
            var allUsers = await UserManager.GetUsers();
            return View(allUsers);
        }
        catch (RedirectRequiredException ex)
        {
            return Redirect(ex.RedirectUri.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Vadim, Using AD Graph API, I can get all the properties except user's **personal site url**. How to get the **personal site url** of an user using REST API ?

Comment: @user31420 Were you successful in getting personal site url through the REST API?

Comment: @SyedMauzeRehan I got it working with help of the this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn790354.aspx#bk_PeopleManagerGetPropertiesFor

Comment: Yes indeed. The problem with my case is that http://<site url>/ needs to be figured out. Discovery service is not a option for me. How can I get this Site URl to make the API call to the begin with?